# My portfolio project doesn't show on project page it shows in different page when I add project it asked to view project

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, portfolio

I'm using construction theme.When I add a new project or category on my website it doesn't show on my website. Only I can see my project whenever I save my project and it give the option to view your post. [image: Here before project 4 it must come from project page] but actually it is not. SNL->Projects->Project 4 it must look like this but when I add some project it doesn't show anywhere. Please help!!!

Comment: Do you have a link to this website?

Comment: http://snlconstruction.co.uk

Comment: Can you explain a little further the steps you took and what the actual issue as its difficult to know from your short explanation

Answer (score 0):

I have a website page called projects. When I post a project or portfolio on my website it doesn't show in project page or anywhere else. Like it's hidden not posted on front view. When I save portfolio Wordpress give tne option to view your post when I click on it, it shows that this project is coming from ABC category. [It is showing like this look SNL Construction ->abc -> Project 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sbpW.png). It must look like this SNL construction->project->abc->project 2. That means the portfolio I'm posting is not going anywhere it's creating its own location. I want is when I post an portfolio it must go in PROJECT or OUR WORK page. Like products goes to their own category.